# proof two general dimension inequalities

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, vector-analysis, low-dimensional-topology

I have just showed that $A+B$ is indeed a subspace by showing it is non empty and closed under multiplication and addition, however I am not sure how to do these types of problems with $\mathbf{dim}$.

**Problem: Dimensions**

$A+B=\left \{ a+b : a\in A, b\in B \right \}$ and $C$ is a vectorspace and $A \subset C, B \subset C$.

Let $a_1,..,a_n$ be elements of $A$ and let $b_1,..,b_k$ be elements of $B$ be two families of vectors in $C$. Let $A=\operatorname{Span}(a_1,..,a_n)$ and $b=\operatorname{Span}(b_1,..,b_k)$

Now, Show that $\mathbf{dim}(A+B)\leq n+k$ and show that $\mathbf{dim}(A+B)\leq \mathbf{dim}(C)$

....................................................................

I am new to the subject and I could use some help since I am really struggling with both span and dim. I get the definitions but no idea on how to approach such a problem.

Comment: You never say who $C$ is.

Comment: Use the fact that dimension of the space spanned by $k$ vectors is at most $k$.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Added now. It is a vectorspace with the two families in it.

Comment: You need to say what the relation between $A$, $B$, and $C$ are. Right now, you say you have $A$ and $B$, and you have some other vector space $C$, and you provide no relation between them. Presumably, you mean that $C$ is a space that contains $A$ and $B$, but you need to *say so explicitly*.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin I thought that was said with the two families being of it.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Yes My bad I noticed i forgot it now. It is in now.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin okay 2 things. first off it is implied and I forgot the small subset detail. second off, It is in the second line. No reason to get overly angry over trivials.

Comment: (1) I’m not angry, I wasn’t angry (not “overly”, not at all). (2) I deleted the comment because you addressed it as I was writing it. In fact, by the time you wrote your comment above I had already deleted it, though perhaps your screen had not refreshed. (3) When asking for help, making it easy for the people you are asking for (free) help from is not a triviality, it is the very least that one should expect from those who are asking. If they can’t be bothered to do so, then they are being cavalier about it.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin I do not see why this rant is relevant at all. Please keep this out of the post.

Comment: It’s not a rant, and it’s not in the post; if you insist on telling me how I feel or what I am doing, do not be surprised if I correct the record.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin No reason to correct any record. Just keep out. This is a waste of everyones time.

Answer (score 1):

Let $C$ be vector space over field $K$. You have proved that $A+B$ is subspace of $C$, then it is itself linear space over $K$. $$A=\operatorname{Span}(a_1,...,a_n)=\bigg\{\sum\limits_{t=1}^{n}\alpha_ta_t\bigg|~\alpha_t \in K\bigg\}.$$
$$B=\operatorname{Span}(b_1,...,b_k)=\biggl\{\sum\limits_{t=1}^{k}\beta_tb_t\;\biggm|~\beta_t \in K\biggr\}.$$
$$A+B=\operatorname{Span}(a_1,...,a_n)+\operatorname{Span}(b_1,...,b_k)=\biggl\{\sum\limits_{t=1}^{n}\alpha_ta_t+\sum\limits_{i=1}^{k}\beta_ib_i\;\biggm|~\alpha_t,\beta_i \in K\biggr\}=\biggl\{\sum\limits_{t=1}^{n+k}\gamma_tc_t\:\biggm|~\gamma_t \in K\biggr\},$$ where $c_t=a_t$ if $t \leq n$ and $c_t=b_{t-n}$, if $n+1 \leq t \leq n+k$. So basis of $A+B$ contains no more than $n+k$ vectors. Therefore $\dim(A+B) \leq n+k$.

2)If $\dim(C)=\infty$, then inequlity $\dim(A+B) \leq \dim(C)$ is obious.
Let $\dim(C) < \infty$ and $\{e_1,...,e_s\}$ be basis of $A+B$. Hence, $\{e_1,...,e_s\}$ is linearly independent in $C$ over $K$. Basis of $C$ is maximal linearly independent system of vectors from $C$ and $\{e_1,...,e_s\}$ is some linearly independent system. Therefore $\dim(A+B)=s \leq \dim(C)$.

Comment: Sorry added details about $C$ now. Does this still hold?

Comment: Yes, it does holds.

Comment: Okay thanks a lot this clears it up for me

Comment: Mark my post as an answer please

Comment: Hey a small question; why is your index in the $A+B$ for $\beta$ $"i"$ and not $"t"$

Comment: And the sentence from "Basis of C is maximal linearly independent system of vectors from C and {e1,...,es} is some linearly independent system. Therefore dim(A+B)=s≤dim(C)." is a bit unclear. Could you clarify?

Comment: Maximal linearly independent system of vectors is set of vectors with property: they are linearly independent, but if you add any vector, linearl indpendance will disappear. We have linearly independent system, it may be maximal, but it cannot be bigger than maximal.

Comment: okay so the cardinality of the basis is the dimension of $C$ and thus the maximal number of linear independent vectors in C.

Comment: yes. You are right.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**:

Supposing $C$ is the vector space everyone lives in, you  have $\dim A \le n$ and $\dim B\le k$. Concerning $A+B$, you have  the short exact sequence
\begin{alignat}{2}
0\longrightarrow A\cap B &{} \longrightarrow & A\oplus B &{}\longrightarrow A+B\longrightarrow 0 \\ c&\longmapsto& (c,-c)\\
&&(a,b)&\longmapsto a+b
\end{alignat}
which shows that $\:\dim A+\dim B=\dim(A\oplus B) =\dim(A+B)+\dim(A\cap B)$.